# Why does Content-Length header field from actual filesize in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, http, networking, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to collect network statistics of Chrome using HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 to connect to a Caddy v2 server. Compression is disabled to enforce certain filesizes.

The Chrome Dev Tools display a filesize of ~3-4kB, even though the files do have a size of 100kB as shown in the header, which also have a similar filesize on the server (Picture 1-3). Why does Chrome display this by far to small filesize?

(Even though I'm using http3 here, the same happens for HTTP/2)

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]
[image: Header]
[image]

The Command im Running chrome with:

```
google-chrome-unstable -media-cache-size=1 --disk-cache-size=1 --enable-quic --quic-version="h3-27" --enable-logging=stderr --v=1 immocodes.com > ~/log.txt
```

My versions:

```
Chrome Dev Version 84.0.4143.2 (Official Build) dev (64-bit) 
Client Linux Ideapad 5.3.0-51-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 21:09:44 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
Server: Caddy 2.0.0
```

My Server Config:

```
{
    experimental_http3 }

www.immocodes.com {
        root * /usr/share/caddy/
        templates
        file_server
        encode zstd gzip }

# redirect no-www to www immocodes.com {
        redir https://www.immocodes.com }
```

**Edit 1: HTTP/2 + Hovering**

[image: HTTP/2 + Hovering]

Comment: The size means the network request's size. To see the resource size either hover the value or switch to large rows in the options (the gear icon in the toolbar).

Comment: I've added a picture of the hovering. The resource size does still seem to be smaller than the actual file size

Comment: I guess the files aren't really jpegs but rather highly-compressible dummies. I don't see how you disable compression in your config.

Comment: I disabled encoding by using an empty "accept-encoding" header field. The images are indeed dummys consisting of reptitive text. Also the response header does not contain information about compression

Comment: Probably a bug. Check the internals in chrome://net-export just in case and report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Also try `accept-encoding: identity`